# django: Update dabatase table with a formset

Tags: python, django

I am confused about formsets. I built a form and a view to insert one database table row that working just fine, and I just built a formset in a view to be able to insert several rows at once. My issue is that the formset does not seem to work. Nothing gets changed in the DB.

Here is what my form look like:

```
class ProcurementOperationRecordForm(forms.ModelForm):
   
    class Meta:
        model = replenishment
        fields = ('Id', 'Quantity', 'NetAmount', 'Supplier', 'SellPrice')
```

and here is what my former view looked like:

```
#def New_Purchase(request):
    #if request.method == 'POST':
        #form = ProcurementOperationRecordForm(request.POST)
        
        #if form.is_valid():
            
            #form.save()
            
        #quantity = form.cleaned_data.get('Quantity')
        #id = form.cleaned_data.get('Id')
        #update = replenishment.objects.filter(Id = id).update(StockOnOrder =+ quantity)
        #update2 = Item2.objects.filter(reference = id).update(en_cours_de_reception =+ quantity)
        #quantity = form.cleaned_data.get('Quantity')
        #id = form.cleaned_data.get('Id')
        #update = replenishment.objects.filter(Id = id).update(StockOnOrder = (StockOnOrder + quantity))
        
        #return redirect('/dash2.html') 
    #else:
        #form = ProcurementOperationRecordForm()
            
    #context = {'form': form,}
            
    #return render(request, 'new_purchase.html', context)
```

and here is what my formset view looks like:

```
def New_Purchase(request):
    context = {}
    form = formset_factory(ProcurementOperationRecordForm, extra = 3)
    formset = form()
    context['formset'] = formset
    
    return render(request, 'new_purchase.html', context)
```

I don't know what to do to make this formset works, would someone have a clue that could unblock the situation?

UPDATE: I have modified my formset as such:

```
ef New_Purchase(request):
    context = {}
    form = formset_factory(ProcurementOperationRecordForm, extra = 3)
    
    if request.method == POST:
        
        formset = form(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            
        quantity = form.cleaned_data.get('Quantity')
        id = form.cleaned_data.get('Id')
        update = replenishment.objects.filter(Id = id).update(StockOnOrder =+ quantity)
        update2 = Item2.objects.filter(reference = id).update(en_cours_de_reception =+ quantity)
            
            
        
        return redirect('/dash2.html') 
    
    else:
        form = formset_factory(ProcurementOperationRecordForm, extra = 3)
        
    
        context['formset'] = form
    
        return render(request, 'new_purchase.html', context)
```

but now I get the error:

```
AttributeError at /new_purchase.html
'ProcurementOperationRecordFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'save'
```

UPDATE 2:

I got it somewhat working doing this:

```
def New_Purchase(request):
    context = {}
    form = modelformset_factory(replenishment, form=ProcurementOperationRecordForm, max_num= 4,extra = 3)
 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = form(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            
        quantity = form.cleaned_data.get('Quantity')
        id = form.cleaned_data.get('Id')
        update = replenishment.objects.filter(Id = id).update(StockOnOrder =+ quantity)
        update2 = Item2.objects.filter(reference = id).update(en_cours_de_reception =+ quantity)

        return redirect('/dash2.html') 
    
    else:
        form = modelformset_factory(replenishment, form=ProcurementOperationRecordForm, extra = 3)
        
    
        context['formset'] = form
    
        return render(request, 'new_purchase.html', context)
```

Although I tried to specify the max rows parameters as mentionned in the docs, this view output the entire replenishment table content. I am trying to get only 3 or 4 empty rows to insert them into the replenishment table. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 main differences between your form and your formset.
when you work with form you provide your form with user data `form = ProcurementOperationRecordForm(request.POST)` when you work with formset you don't. Change your code to `formset = form(request.POST)`

and you check user data and save it to database if it's correct

```
if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

do the same with formsets

```
if formset.is_valid():
    formset.save()
```

and you need to change `formset_factory` to `modelformset_factory`

```
modelformset_factory(replenishment, form=ProcurementOperationRecordForm, extra = 3)
```

when you modified your code you need to modify updates too. you need to do it for every form in your formset

```
for check_form in formset:
        quantity = check_form .cleaned_data.get('Quantity')
        id = check_form .cleaned_data.get('Id')
        update = replenishment.objects.filter(Id = id).update(StockOnOrder =+ quantity)
        update2 = Item2.objects.filter(reference = id).update(en_cours_de_reception =+ quantity)
```

Comment: i tried this, it does not work, I get the error ```AttributeError: 'ProcurementOperationRecordFormFormSet' object has no attribute 'save'```, check my updated post

Comment: change `formset_factory` to `modelformset_factory` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Comment: did you change it everywhere (you have 2 instance of formset_factory_?

Comment: yes sir, I got it working, somehow a redirection problem made it weird. However, the update part after saving the formset gets ignored

Comment: actually, something is off, all the ```replenishment``` table data gets outputed in the template

Comment: Thank you for your help, I can update but this does not work to create multiple rows in the database table